# Do I need to merge EPF amount of different companies?

Tags: india, employment, employer, provident-fund, epf

I'm from India. Everyone is saying that there should be only one EPF account, what does that mean? I have a single UAN number and since starting my professional career I have changed 2 employers and am currently at 3rd employer. In EPF account shows that there are 3 different `Member Id`s.

Is it OK? or do I need to merge them into a single one?
If yes, please provide the process to merge them.

***Note: I have only one UAN number***